# Julia 1.6.2 not appearing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter

I have installed julia 1.6.2 , jupyter notebook and anaconda 3 according to this website:

https://datatofish.com/add-julia-to-jupyter/

I have also checked other websites and the steps of installation were similar. However, I have a problem in step 5 of the above link, as Julia 1.0 doesn't appear and only Python appears. ( Text File, Folder, and Terminal also appear in the Others section )

Any ideas on what the problem is? I have also set the environment variable of Julia by going to System Variables and adding the bin folder of julia to Path. ( Windows 10 OS)

Also, after installing Julia, these were the lines I entered to install other things.

```
import Pkg
# installs IJulia package
Pkg.add("IJulia")
using IJulia
# launch Jupyter notebook
notebook()
```

After these, I opened julia again and typed:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("NBInclude")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia 1.0 is really old, please use the latest 1.6.2 and follow official installation guide for Jupyter notebook support (IJulia): https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/dev/manual/installation/

Usually, it's as simple as `]build IJulia`, where pressing `]` at the REPL drops you into the `pkg>` mode

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I had installed 1.6.2 and I still have this problem. I'll update my post.

Comment: @NaturalQuestioner NBInclude is irrelevant here for your problem at hand. What if you do `Pkg.build("IJulia")` before `notebook()`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Btw, could you explain what does Pkg.build("IJulia") do?

Comment: it's explained in the link to docs above. Basically it adds a jupyter kernel spec for Julia (so that it shows up)

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue also. To solve it, you just need to rebuild your `IJulia` kernel by running command below on Julia apps:

```
Using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
Pkg.build("IJulia")
```

Comment: I appreciate that you may not be a native English speaker, but *please* try to improve the grammar of your post.

Comment: Thanks so much! The Pkg.build("IJulia") did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer of @jling. Use an up-to-date julia version if you can. In case you need an old julia version, I have recently created a docker container that provides julia 1.1 inside jupyter notebooks (and I think python as well).
You can find the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/cherrywoods/HorizontalCAS

Nevermind all the code, only the Dockerfile is relevant (and maybe the last section of the Readme). I guess this dockee fiöe should also work with julia 1.0 if you change the file accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I had installed 1.6.2 and I still have this problem. I have updated my post.