# R and julia not showing up on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, julia

I'm trying to install R and Julia on Jupiter notebook. I thought everything installed fine until I opened Jupiter notebook but there's only Python. I'm using Windows 11.

For R:

```
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.*\bin
R
install.packages("devtools")
# selected USA OR

devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")
# didn't give me an option to select "1"

IRkernel::installspec()

q()

y
```

For julia:

```
julia
using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

I tried a couple of times but it just showed the location of the files.

I closed my admin command prompt and opened a regular one, tried Jupiter lab but there's only Python.

Comment: I would suggest, removing the bold fonts and keep everything in one size, the bold font does not help structuring the question. In addition, your problem description is not very clear. Please try to define precisely what you have done so far and which steps you have followed. 
Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785709/julia-1-6-2-not-appearing-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0):

A `Pkg.build("IJulia")` can help here, it will make sure that the kernel is installed properly and afterwards you should be able to see it in Jupyter (maybe reload it once more).